# Quantum Mechanics Book

Tags: book-recommendation, quantum-mechanics

I'm a postgraduate student and I'm looking for a Quantum mechanics book which has a great level of detail. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of detail? Why ask on a math rather than on a physics forum? Have you been unsatisfied with recommendations that you found on similar threads?

Comment: Hey LittleO, I want to see the perspective from mathematicians. I have looked online but haven't seen many reviews about a particular book. I was wondering if people here had any recommendation. As for the detail, I would expect topics to be covered thoroughly and up there with the likes of students preparing for their PhD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are asking this on Math SE and not on Physics I assume a mathematical treatment is what you are looking for. Consider Mackey's *Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics*,

> Designed for students familiar with abstract mathematical concepts but
>   possessing little knowledge of physics, this text focuses on
>   generality and careful formulation rather than problem-solving. Its
>   author, a member of the distinguished National Academy of Science,
>   based this graduate-level text on the course he taught at Harvard
>   University.

http://store.doverpublications.com/0486435172.html

Comment: Yes, that's right. I should've made it more clear. I'm aware that there is a Physics SE, but wanted to see the perspective from people here.

Comment: Personal history. I am one of the four students who prepared lecture notes during Mackey's first version of this course.

Comment: Thank you Ethan Bolker for the recommendation.

Comment: I will get this. Thank you very much. I can't seem to give you an upvote as it deems my reputation to be too low. However, I'm able to accept your answer. Hope this helps.